# how to create conda environment with python already installed

Tags: python, anaconda

I have already install python 3.10.5 under path /usr/local/bin/python and using it for a while. Lots of package installed. But now I need to use anaconda and after I installed anaconda, another python was installed with it, python 3.11.3 under ~/anaconda3/bin/python. How can I create an environment with my old python 3.10.5?

I tried using terminal conda create --name myenv python=/usr/local/bin/python
got error invalid package specification: python=/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: use alias, defined python path there and with that create

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

You **should not** try to force Anaconda to use your */usr/local/bin/python*. That defeats the purpose of using a virtual environment manager like Anaconda. See the documentation at https://numdifftools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/how-to/create_virtual_env_with_conda.html. This should work:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.10.5
```

Comment: Your anwer makes it sound like the link you ahve psoted are the official `anaconda` or `conda` docs, but they are some third party package describing how to create a virtual env with conda.